# arm + serial + uart + monitor in visual c#

Tags: c#, c, arm, uart

**

### SOLVED: I enabled the property DTR of the serial port component of visual studio. Now it is working fine. Thank you all.

### **

I need some help.

I wrote a program in for my arm processor that sends the character 'a' through UART (USB). The frequency is 1 character/second.
So, I wrote a program in Visual C# to receive this character and show in a text box. Just a very simple program.

The configurations of the serial communications are OK (baud_rate, stopbit, parity, data_bits)

**The problem: I cannot read the character sent by the arm processor.**

**The facts:**

**1 - the arm program is working correctly in Putty.**

**2 - my visual c# program is working correctly with arduino board that has the same code that arm has.**

Please guys, look my codes and if you can, help me.

This is the code of ARM:

```
#include "inc/hw_ints.h"
#include "inc/hw_memmap.h"
#include "inc/hw_types.h"
#include "driverlib/debug.h"
#include "driverlib/gpio.h"
#include "driverlib/interrupt.h"
#include "driverlib/sysctl.h"
#include "driverlib/uart.h"
#include "drivers/rit128x96x4.h"

//*****************************************************************************
//
//! \addtogroup example_list
//! <h1>UART Echo (uart_echo)</h1>
//!
//! This example application utilizes the UART to echo text.  The first UART
//! (connected to the FTDI virtual serial port on the evaluation board) will be
//! configured in 115,200 baud, 8-n-1 mode.  All characters received on the
//! UART are transmitted back to the UART.
//
//*****************************************************************************

//*****************************************************************************
//
// The error routine that is called if the driver library encounters an error.
//
//*****************************************************************************
#ifdef DEBUG
void
__error__(char *pcFilename, unsigned long ulLine)
{
}
#endif

//*****************************************************************************
//
// The UART interrupt handler.
//
//*****************************************************************************
void
UARTIntHandler(void)
{
    unsigned long ulStatus;

    //
    // Get the interrrupt status.
    //
    ulStatus = UARTIntStatus(UART0_BASE, true);

    //
    // Clear the asserted interrupts.
    //
    UARTIntClear(UART0_BASE, ulStatus);

    //
    // Loop while there are characters in the receive FIFO.
    //
    while(UARTCharsAvail(UART0_BASE))
    {
        //
        // Read the next character from the UART and write it back to the UART.
        //
        //UARTCharPutNonBlocking(UART0_BASE, UARTCharGetNonBlocking(UART0_BASE));
        UARTCharPutNonBlocking(UART0_BASE,'a');

        SysCtlDelay(16666666); //1.2 ms


    }
}

//*****************************************************************************
//
// Send a string to the UART.
//
//*****************************************************************************
void
UARTSend(const unsigned char *pucBuffer, unsigned long ulCount)
{
    //
    // Loop while there are more characters to send.
    //
    while(ulCount--)
    {
        //
        // Write the next character to the UART.
        //
        UARTCharPutNonBlocking(UART0_BASE, *pucBuffer++);
    }
}

//*****************************************************************************
//
// This example demonstrates how to send a string of data to the UART.
//
//*****************************************************************************
int
main(void)
{
    //
    // Set the clocking to run directly from the crystal.
    //
    //SysCtlClockSet(SYSCTL_SYSDIV_1 | SYSCTL_USE_OSC | SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN | SYSCTL_XTAL_8MHZ);
    SysCtlClockSet(SYSCTL_SYSDIV_4 | SYSCTL_USE_PLL | SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN | SYSCTL_XTAL_8MHZ);

    //
    // Initialize the OLED display and write status.
    //
    RIT128x96x4Init(1000000);
    RIT128x96x4StringDraw("UART Echo",            36,  0, 15);
    RIT128x96x4StringDraw("Port:   Uart 0",       12, 16, 15);
    RIT128x96x4StringDraw("Baud:   115,200 bps",  12, 24, 15);
    RIT128x96x4StringDraw("Data:   8 Bit",        12, 32, 15);
    RIT128x96x4StringDraw("Parity: None",         12, 40, 15);
    RIT128x96x4StringDraw("Stop:   1 Bit",        12, 48, 15);

    //
    // Enable the peripherals used by this example.
    //
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_UART0);
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOA);

    //
    // Enable processor interrupts.
    //
    IntMasterEnable();

    //
    // Set GPIO A0 and A1 as UART pins.
    //
    GPIOPinTypeUART(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_1);

    //
    // Configure the UART for 115,200, 8-N-1 operation.
    //
    UARTConfigSetExpClk(UART0_BASE, SysCtlClockGet(), 9600,
                        (UART_CONFIG_WLEN_8 | UART_CONFIG_STOP_ONE |
                         UART_CONFIG_PAR_NONE));

    //
    // Enable the UART interrupt.
    //
    IntEnable(INT_UART0);
    UARTIntEnable(UART0_BASE, UART_INT_RX | UART_INT_RT);

    UARTFIFOEnable(UART0_BASE);
    UARTEnable(UART0_BASE);

    //
    // Prompt for text to be entered.
    //
    UARTSend((unsigned char *)"Enter text: ", 12);

    //
    // Loop forever echoing data through the UART.
    //
    while(1)
    {

    }
}
```

This is the Visual C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;  

namespace interfaceArduinoVS2013
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        string RxString;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timerCOM.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void atualizaListaCOMs()
        {
            int i;
            bool quantDiferente;    //flag para sinalizar que a quantidade de portas mudou

            i = 0;
            quantDiferente = false;

            //se a quantidade de portas mudou
            if (comboBox1.Items.Count == SerialPort.GetPortNames().Length)
            {
                foreach (string s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
                {
                    if (comboBox1.Items[i++].Equals(s) == false)
                    {
                        quantDiferente = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                quantDiferente = true;
            }

            //Se não foi detectado diferença
            if (quantDiferente == false)
            {
                return;                     //retorna
            }

            //limpa comboBox
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();

            //adiciona todas as COM diponíveis na lista
            foreach (string s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(s);
            }
            //seleciona a primeira posição da lista
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        private void timerCOM_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            atualizaListaCOMs();
        }

        private void btConectar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen == false)
            {
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.PortName = comboBox1.Items[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
                    serialPort1.Open();

                }
                catch
                {
                    return;

                }
                if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
                {
                    btConnect.Text = "Disconnect";
                    comboBox1.Enabled = false;

                }
            }
            else
            {

                try
                {
                    serialPort1.Close();
                    comboBox1.Enabled = true;
                    btConnect.Text = "Connect";
                }
                catch
                {
                    return;
                }

            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(serialPort1.IsOpen == true)  // if port opened
             serialPort1.Close();            //close the port
        }

        private void btEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(serialPort1.IsOpen == true)         
            serialPort1.Write(textBoxSend.Text);  //send the text in the textbox
            RxString = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
            MessageBox.Show(RxString);
        }

        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            RxString = serialPort1.ReadExisting(); //read data from serial port
            MessageBox.Show(RxString);
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(trataDadoRecebido));   //call another thread to write the data on textbox

        }

        private void trataDadoRecebido(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            textBoxReceive.AppendText(RxString);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this C# code seems to be missing the function prototypes and other definitions.   Does it cleanly compile?

Comment: for lines like: 'if(serialPort1.IsOpen == true)' never compare == true.  this is acceptable: 'if(serialPort1.IsOpen != false)' or even better: 'if(serialPort1.IsOpen)'

Comment: It is compiling normally.

Comment: Actually, the code is working normally with arduino board. But I cannot use arduino on the whole project.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have a problem of baud rate. In the C# code i do not see anywhere you setting the baud rate of the COM port. if that is 115200 as you print on the ARM board then your problem is in the ARM board itself. You are printing 115,200 as baud rate but you are initializing the ARM board at 9600 8N1

```
//
// Configure the UART for 115,200, 8-N-1 operation.
//
UARTConfigSetExpClk(UART0_BASE, SysCtlClockGet(), 9600,
                    (UART_CONFIG_WLEN_8 | UART_CONFIG_STOP_ONE |
                     UART_CONFIG_PAR_NONE));
```

Initialize corectly both ends of the communication line before opening the ports and try again. Usually a smaller baud rate on a transmitter will result in no characters printed on a high speed configured receiver. On the other hand, a slow configured receiver(9600) will capture some garbage from a high speed transmitter.

Comment: The baud rate of the COM is configured in the property of the the component as 9600. My arm code is working in putty perfectly and my c# code is working with arduino board (that has the same code as arm).

Comment: can you check the other settings for com port like stop bits parity etc in c# code? there is no other reason except mismatch of these settings assuming you do not do any hw changes when you switch from arduino to ARM in terms of PC port & stuff

Comment: I've already checked those settings. They are right. 8-bits data, 1 stop bit, no parity.

Comment: Do you think that I need to force through code these properties instead of using the property option of visual C#?

Comment: ok then. so putty connected to the com port of the receiving PC can receive successfully the data transmitted by ARM board. it is indeed strange.